# Uncaught TypeError: listview has no method 'listview'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, mobile

in my code I am trying to add items onto my unordered list called datalist
I get data and I append it, Im trying to get listview('refresh') to work because I want the added item to also have the same css and designs as the other items that were originally in my  ul. but i get error in my console (the error is the title of this question)

My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Boot Camp</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getdata() {
$.ajax({
url:'http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/lists/movies/upcoming.json?page_limit=16&page=1&country=us&apikey=k4uaze4937mw3hf82upstxqw',
type:'GET',
//    contentType: "application/json",
dataType:'jsonp',
success:function(data){
    var movies = data.movies;
    var title1 = movies[0].title; 
    alert(data);
    alert(title1);
    $('#datalist').append('<li>'+title1+'</li>').listview('refresh');
},

error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert('request failed :'+xhr);
                    alert('request failed :'+textStatus);
    alert('request failed :'+errorThrown);
}
}); 
};
setInterval(getdata(), 10000);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div data-role="header"> 
<h1>Upcoming Movies</h1> 
</div> 
<ul data-role="listview" id="datalist">
<li><img src="http://content8.flixster.com/movie/11/17/20/11172082_mob.jpg" class="ui-li-thumb"><h3 class="ui-li-heading">Warning</h3><p class="ui-li-desc">hot</p>        </li>
<li><a href="javascript:alert('hi')">Audi</a></li>
<li><a href="bmw.html">BMW</a></li>
</ul></body></html>
```

Comment: Why do you have two `jquery` libs on your site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are loading two versions of jQuery so the second definition remove the first and other plugin binded to it.

Remove the second, old, script include:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and it will work fine.